# How to merge crosstab info down in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, crosstab, mailmerge

Not sure if this is possible but I'm hoping it is. I am using MS Access for Estate Planning for work. I've gotten to the point where I've got the data to look like this:

| File_Name | Executor_1 | Executor_2 | Beneficiary_1 | Beneficiary_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hill, Hank | Peggy Hill |  | Peggy Hill |  |
| Hill, Hank |  | Bobby Hill |  | Bobby Hill |
| Gribble, Dale | Nancy Gribble |  |  |  |
| Gribble, Dale |  | Joseph Gribble | Joseph Gribble |  |
| Gribble, Dale |  |  |  | John Redcorn |

But I need it to look like this:

| File_Name | Executor_1 | Executor_2 | Beneficiary_1 | Beneficiary_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hill, Hank | Peggy Hill | Bobby Hill | Peggy Hill | Bobby Hill |
| Gribble, Dale | Nancy Gribble | Joseph Gribble | Joseph Gribble | John Redcorn |

I need it in the latter format so I can use MailMerge in word and create the Will. Can anyone provide any guidance? We don't currently use any software for Est. Planning so anything beats having to go into Word manually and retype everything. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Edit:
This is what the SQL looks like:

```
TRANSFORM Last(File_Roles.File_Name) AS LastOfFile_Name

SELECT File_Roles.Executor_1, 
File_Roles.Executor_2, 
File_Roles.Beneficiary_1, 
File_Roles.Beneficiary_2, 
File_Roles.Trustee_1,
File_Roles.Trustee_2, 
File_Roles.Guardian_1, 
File_Roles.Guardian_2, 
File_Roles.ATTY_IF_1, File_Roles.ATTY_IF_2, 
File_Roles.HCATTY_IF_1, 
File_Roles.HCATTY_IF_2

FROM File_Roles

GROUP BY File_Roles.Executor_1, 
File_Roles.Executor_2, 
File_Roles.Beneficiary_1, 
File_Roles.Beneficiary_2,
File_Roles.Trustee_1,
File_Roles.Trustee_2, 
File_Roles.Guardian_1, 
File_Roles.Guardian_2, 
File_Roles.ATTY_IF_1, 
File_Roles.ATTY_IF_2, 
File_Roles.HCATTY_IF_1, 
File_Roles.HCATTY_IF_2

PIVOT File_Roles.File_Name;
```

Comment: Your query makes no sense. It features the `File_Name` column as column heading as well as value. The purpose of a crosstab query is to turn rows into columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GROUP BY and MAX()

```sql
SELECT
    t.File_Name,
    MAX(t.Executor_1) As Executor_1,
    MAX(t,Executor_2) As Executor_2,
    MAX(t.Beneficiary_1) As Beneficiary_1,
    MAX(t.Beneficiary_2) As Beneficiary_2
FROM table_or_query t
GROUP BY File_Name
```

But maybe you can fix your original crosstab query to do this right away. Probably you are doing the grouping wrong. You must group by `File_Name` in the crosstab query and apply `Max` to the total row of the value (so it is difficult to say without seeing this query).

- `GROUP BY File_Name` means that one row is created for each distinct value of File_Name.
- Since this will merge several rows into one, you must specify an aggregate function for every column in the SELECT list not listed in the GROUP BY clause. This can be e.g. SUM(), AVG(), MIN() or MAX(). See [SQL Aggregate Functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sql-aggregate-functions-a810ee71-c1cd-43d7-9c55-8005f1893be5) for a complete list. Since any `Null` value is considered to be less than any other value, `MAX()` will take this non-Null value from the merged rows.

Comment: I've edited the post to show the SQL

Comment: This works! This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!! Could you tell me exactly what I'm doing here so I can do it on my own next time?